# iFrame onLoad in custom Gutenberg block

Tags: javascript, events, callbacks, iframe, block-editor

I have this code that I am trying to rewrite for Gutenberg block:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <iframe onload="javascript:resizeIframe(this);" 
            src="/modularconvbox/modularconvbox.php?type=newsletter&amp;title=Subsribe to our newsletter!&amp;text=Once in a lifetime opportunity to get all our latest posts delivered right to your inbox!&amp;button=Subscribe!&amp;secret=not_set"
             scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width:100%="" style="width: 1px; min-width: 100%; border: none; height: 70px;">
            </iframe>
      function resizeIframe(obj){
         {obj.style.height = 0;};
         {obj.style.height = (obj.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+70) + "px";}
      }
    </script>
```

This is my save() function:

```
save({ attributes }) {
  return (

    <iframe
      onLoad={resizeIframe}
      src={"https://domain.me/modularconvbox/modularconvbox.php?type=newsletter&title=" + attributes.title + "&text=" +attributes.text + "&button=" + attributes.button + "!&secret=" + attributes.button} 
      scrolling= {"no"} 
      frameborder= {"0"} 
      width= {"100%"} 
    />

  );
}
```

I don't know how to wirte this resizeIframe function. It seems nothing I write here works. I've tried to test with:

```
 onLoad={() => console.log('LOADED')}
```

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: I would note that this is perhaps more applicable to general React components than you might realise, just note that you may not necessarily want to apply it to the `save` function, try the `edit` function instead

Comment: In particular: https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg-examples/blob/master/05-recipe-card-esnext/block.js, the `save` function determines what gets put in the document, not what is displayed on screen, so it doesn't make sense to apply JS libraries to it

Comment: @TomJNowell Could you, please, be more precise about how I should change the code to add an onLoad function to the iFrame that will be saved? I am still trying to get familiar with React

Comment: I don't know how to integrate it, else I'd answer, but the answer here would be the same as any answer in generic React, except it would be in an `edit` function not a `save` function. Applying it in the `save` function makes no sense, similar to how to apply a JS library directly to a database table